# Use cookie of site1 in site2 for authentication deployed on azure

Tags: azure, cookies, dns, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

I have a website, site1.azurewebsites.net, which has the db and another site, site2.azurewebsites.net, with no db and what I want is when I login to my site1 I want to be able to browse without having to login to site2 but my code don't seem to work. I only have configured the web.config file of both sites but it is not working.

Comment: Did you set the same [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Thanks for the reply. Yup, I did. Here is my web.config code for both files <forms loginUrl="Account/Login"
  name=".AspNet.ApplicationCookie"
  cookieless="UseCookies"
  requireSSL="false"
  protection="All"
  path="/"
  domain="test-website1.azurewebsites.net"
  enableCrossAppRedirects="false"
  timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Also my machine key  <machineKey
      validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE"
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F"
      validation="SHA1"
      compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"/>

Comment: Try changing your domain to: domain="azurewebsites.net"